# OneDrive REST api sortby

Tags: onedrive

I know you can add the sortby parameter to OneDrive rest calls to sort by name
size
lastModifiedDateTime

in OneDrive personal

However, I'd like to be able to perform the sort with the folders sorted separately so that they remainin on top.  Is there a way to make this work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

use the root folder as example, does https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children?select=id,name,folder work for you?